# Show that the characteristics equation for a $2\times 2$ matrix is $\lambda^2 - \mathrm{tr}(A)\lambda + \det(A)=0$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Can someone help me show that the characteristics equation for a $2\times 2$ matrix, say $A$, can be written as: 
$$
\lambda^2 - \mathrm{tr}(A)\lambda + \det(A) = 0,$$

where $\mathrm{tr}(A)$ is the sum of the diagonal entries of $A$?

I'm having trouble figuring out the question, we haven't been taught this yet. Please help.

Comment: http://www.soest.hawaii.edu/martel/Courses/GG303/Eigenvectors.pdf (Example 3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternative proof: The the roots of the characteristic polynomial $\chi_A$ of $A$ are the eigenvalues of $A$, so if $\lambda_0,\lambda_1$ are eigenvalues of $A$, by [Vieta's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas) we have

$$ \chi_A(\lambda) = \lambda^2 - \lambda (\lambda_0 + \lambda_1) + \lambda_0\lambda_1
$$
Since $\operatorname{tr} A = \lambda_0 + \lambda_1, \det A = \lambda_0\lambda_1$,

$$ \chi_A(\lambda) = \lambda^2 - \lambda \operatorname{tr} A + \det A
$$

Answer (score 1):

$$A=\left(\begin{matrix} a & b\\ c & d\\ \end{matrix}\right).$$

The characteristic polynomial is $$\det (A-\lambda I)=(a-\lambda)(d-\lambda)-bc=ad-a\lambda-d\lambda+\lambda^2-bc.$$ Setting this polynomial equal to zero we have $$\lambda^2-(a+d)\lambda+ad-bc=0.$$